# Generic method not overriding similar generic method in superclass -> Which one is used?

Tags: java, generics, ambiguous

Given this situation:

```
 public class Animal {

    public <T> void genericMethod(T t){
        System.out.println("Inside generic method on animal with parameter " + t.toString());
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    public <T extends Cat> void genericMethod(T t){
        System.out.println("Inside generic method on cat with parameter " + t.toString());
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.genericMethod(cat);
    }
}
```

The method `genericMethod()` in class `Cat` is definitely NOT overriding the superclass method (and the compiler complains if I add `@Override` signature) which is reasonable, as the requirements to the type `T` are different.

But I do not quite understand, how the compiler decides which of the two methods to use in the call `cat.genericMethod(cat)` in the main method. Because actually both methods are visible and both are applicable. I would have expected a compiler error like "ambigous function call" here. Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: basically there are two types of generics in this case, bounded and un-bounded. the first one is unbounded, so the compiler erases it to `Object`; the second one is bounded and `javac` erases it to the bound, which is `Cat`, the rest is obvious probably...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two methods have a different erasure due to the generic type bound of the sub-class method.

For the super class method the erasure is:

```
public void genericMethod(Object t)
```

For the sub class method the erasure is:

```
public void genericMethod(Cat t)
```

Method overloading resolution rules choose the method with the best matching arguments. Therefore when you pass a `Cat` argument, the second (sub-class) method is chosen.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are talking about erasure, it means you say it is a runtime decision?
My understanding (see my answer below) was that it was a compile-time decision.

Comment: @VictorNoël No, it's a compile time decision. Method overloading resolution is done at compile time.

Comment: Then you can't say it is because of erasure, that's not coherent :)

Comment: @VictorNoël You must talk about erasure, since otherwise both methods have the signature `genericMethod(T t)` and you can't say that one has a more specific argument type than the other.

Comment: @VictorNoël `javac` does the erasure and  it decides what method to call in case of overloading too, this is very easy to see from the byte code

Comment: I agree with both of you about the conclusion and how javac works with erasure: my point was just that erasure is the result of the compilation into bytecode, and the choice of which method to use is done before, not after.
Of course there are links between the result of erasure and the election of the method, but it's not purely correct to say that it is because of erasure that javac choose one of the method.
javac choose one of the method simply because it is the most specific amongst all the method that can be used for this argument.

Comment: @VictorNoël exactly. first erasure then choosing the correct method

Comment: @Eugene that's not what I said ^^ I said "first selection of correct method then erasure", but I can only infer that from the link I posted below, I may be wrong, so maybe you have sources on that?

Comment: @VictorNoël since you need to know what method to call, I would say that erasure happens first, but no source from me...

Answer (score 3):

Java, at compile time, will choose the [most specific matching method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).
In your example, this means the `Cat` implementation of the method.

THere are two things to notice:

- If you pass to it an `Animal`, it is obvious that only the method declared in Animal will be used (since it doesn't match the `T extends Cat` constraint).
- If you pass to it a `Cat`:

  1. Java decides that the two methods match (because of the `Cat` parameter)
  2. Because of the aforementioned rule, Java simply take the most specific one (it does not care anymore about the fact that the parameter is a `Cat`).